# wiring a single bathroom fan servicing 2 rooms in the master bathroom suite with 2 separate switches on the same circuit as well as lighting

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch, fan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I wire an exhaust fan to turn on from multiple locations?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/21845/how-can-i-wire-an-exhaust-fan-to-turn-on-from-multiple-locations)

I am having trouble trying to wire a single in-line bathroom fan servicing a master bathroom suite. There is a commode room as well as a shower room, each with its own lighting and switching from a single circuit.  I want to be able to turn on and off the fan and lighting from each room. I have tried in vain using parallel switching which causes the opposite side of the closed switch to become energized rendering it useless. A similar result occurs using 3-way switching. Can I use a relay to energize the fan after the lighting in the circuit or am I just so thick that I cannot see the obvious. I live in rural New York if that helps. Thanks, Multivon

Comment: Are you trying to get one switch in each room to turn on the local light AND fan (eg, http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/21845) or do you just want a fan switch in each room (3-way, or timers so either turn on the fan), and a separate light switch in each room (which only turns on the local light)? Hint: two switches in each room is significantly simpler, and IMHO using count-down timers is one of the best ways to control an exhaust fan.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not typical, and will likely require custom designed circuitry or a redesign of your current configuration. If you are open to using 4 switches (1 for each light, and 2 for the fan) this can be done, but you're not going to accomplish this easily with only 2 switches.

Comment: @multivon: Are you the same person as [vernon](http://diy.stackexchange.com/users/9813/vernon), who asked the (very similar) question that this one is linked to?  If so, your accounts can be merged if you want. See this for details: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/146318